# TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float when normalizing RGB channel of images

Tags: python, rgb

i try to change the value of RGB channel with this function i created

```
def color_norm(image_norm):
  pixels = np.array(image_norm)
  ar_mean = np.mean(pixels, axis=(0,1)) 
  (H,W) = image_norm.shape[:2]

  for x in range(H):
    for y in range(W):
      Ri = image_norm[:,:,0]
      Gi = image_norm[:,:,1]
      Bi = image_norm[:,:,2]
      R = Ri[x,y] = np.min((Ri[x,y]/(ar_mean[0]))*(r))
      if R > 255:
           # saturate value
           R = 255
      else:
          # add normally
          R = R
      G = Gi[x,y] = np.min((Gi[x,y]/(ar_mean[1]))*(g))
      if G > 255:
           # saturate value
           G = 255
      else:
          # add normally
          G = G
      B = Bi[x,y] = np.min((Bi[x,y]/(ar_mean[2]))*(b))
      if B > 255:
           # saturate value
           B = 255
      else:
          # add normally
          B = B
      image_norm[x,y] = [R,G,B]
```

But when I applied this function on my dataset like this

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(20,10))
axes = axes.ravel()
for i, images in enumerate(test_dataset):
  images1 = crop_img(images)
  images2 = cv2.resize(images1, (512,512))
  images3 = color_norm(images2)
  
  axes[i].imshow(images)
  axes[i+4].imshow(images3)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Suddenly it got an error `TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float`
anyone can help?

I try to change the input image but that doesn't work, or anyone know how to stack the RGB channel again instead using like in my code?

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: By the way, your function `return` nothing, so `images3 is None`.

Comment: Double `for` loops over Numpy arrays are pretty much always to be avoided - they are slow and inefficient. Consider making a `float` copy of your array and just using `np.clip()` at the end to deal with saturated values.

Comment: @Demi-Lune should i do it like this `rgb = image_norm[x,y] = [R,G,B]
      return rgb` , but it ends up getting another error `Invalid shape (3,) for image data`

Comment: @MarkSetchell where should I put `np.clip()` ?

Comment: Right at the end to clip all the values in the entire array.